# Best way to select a word

Tags: mark, words

I want to select current word under the cursor without using mouse.
After searching this forum, I learned how double click works.
(I noticed that it is a bit complicated and there were no direct key bindings.)

What is the best way to select current word with only keyboard?
I also don't want to use emacs function or script with a customized binding
because I want to use it universally(Android studio, Jetbrains...)

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Are you asking what keybinding selects the word at point?  It's unclear what you mean by not wanting to use an Emacs function (they're all functions) or customized binding.

Comment: It's funny that such kbd is absent out-of-box for 20 years :/ even MS Word has such feature (F8)

Comment: Many shortcut keys combined with Shift have a selection effect, such as `M-b` + `M-Shift-f`

Answer (score 14):

I usually use <kbd>C-M-SPC</kbd> or, with [easy-kill](https://github.com/leoliu/easy-kill) installed, <kbd>M-w w</kbd>.

Comment: seems that `C-M-Spc` marks a `word_with_underscores` whereas `M-@` (which I have used so far) only marks up until the first underscore.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`expand-region`](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) package to do this and more.

Let `|` be point and `(...)` indicate that `...` is marked.

```
foo-|bar
```

Calling `er/expand-region` once:

```
foo-(|bar)
```

Calling it again:

```
(|foo-bar)
```

Answer (score 6):

`M-@` is `mark-word`, but it does not grab the part of the word that is before point.

You can write a command (or create a keyboard macro) that does `M-<left>` (which is command `left-word`) followed by `M-@`, to pick up also the first part of the word.

For example:

```el
(defun mark-whole-word (&optional arg allow-extend)
  "Like `mark-word', but selects whole words and skips over whitespace.
If you use a negative prefix arg then select words backward.
Otherwise select them forward.

If cursor starts in the middle of word then select that whole word.

If there is whitespace between the initial cursor position and the
first word (in the selection direction), it is skipped (not selected).

If the command is repeated or the mark is active, select the next NUM
words, where NUM is the numeric prefix argument.  (Negative NUM
selects backward.)"
  (interactive "P\np")
  (let ((num  (prefix-numeric-value arg)))
    (unless (eq last-command this-command)
      (if (natnump num)
          (skip-syntax-forward "\\s-")
        (skip-syntax-backward "\\s-")))
    (unless (or (eq last-command this-command)
                (if (natnump num)
                    (looking-at "\\b")
                  (looking-back "\\b")))
      (if (natnump num)
          (left-word)
        (right-word)))
    (mark-word arg allow-extend)))
```

And if you want to point all global `mark-word` key bindings (such as `M-@`) to `mark-whole-word` instead:

```el
(global-set-key [remap mark-word] 'mark-whole-word)
```

Comment: Can `(thing-at-point 'word)` be put to good use here? :)

Comment: @Caterpillar: Not directly. But if you use [Thing At Point Commands](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ThingAtPointCommands) ([`thing-cmds.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/thing-cmds.el)) then you can use `mark-thing` for `"word"`. It does about the same thing as the code presented here.

Comment: For `_id` it only marks `id` instead of `_id`, what should I do to mark complete word? @Drew

Comment: Use `symbol` or `sexp`, not `word`, if you want to include `_`. Or give `_` word syntax instead of symbol syntax in the current buffer.

Answer (score 3):

A solution for users of [evil](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil):

In normal state, just type: `viw`

Answer (score 3):

Place the cursor on either side of the word, then hold the shift key down *and* hold the alt/option key down, and then use the left or right arrow.

If the cursor is not on either side of the word, then hold the alt/option key down and use the left or right arrow key to move to either side of the word *before* selecting it as set forth in the preceding paragraph.

Comment: if you hate arrow keys, you might use M-S-f and M-S-b (forward or backward) to select the word.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I've come up with to mark "around" a word is the fully built in combo of `C-M-SPC C-M-b` (hold down `Ctrl+Meta` then press `Space` and `b`), AKA `mark-sexp` and `backward-sexp`. Once your fingers are trained for the paredit (and relatives) way of `C-M-` all the time, it's really fast. Then you've also got the remaining niceties of multiple presses of `C-M-SPC` to extend the selection. From [Marking Objects](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Marking-Objects.html):

> Repeated invocations extend the region to subsequent expressions, while positive or negative numeric arguments move the mark forward or backward by the specified number of expressions.

*(I used to use `easy-mark`, as mentioned in another answer here, but I couldn't work around it always losing the top of the mark stack, which was just too annoying.)*

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
(defun mark-whole-word ()
  "Like mark-word, but the whole word from the beginning"
  (interactive)
  (backward-word)
  (mark-word))
```